# MySQL 5.7.20 can't set a root password

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

After a fresh mysql 5.7 installation i have a problem with root pw.

I'm trying start mysql with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` and go in to mysql `mysql -u root`

And try to set a password with

```
root@localhost [(none)]> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost [(none)]> ALTER USER 'root@localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

And im getting this error;

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root@localhost'@'%'
```

I tried this way too;

```
root@localhost [mysql]> update user set authentication_string=password('password') where user='root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1
```

Both not working please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (user and host have to be divided with ''):

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

In a case you changed the privelages with DML:

```
update user set authentication_string=password('password') where user='root';
```

You have to run:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: It is not clear what did not work for you. Did you try to apply the procedure for [reseting permissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)?